# Katalon or Java+Junit+Cucumber to automate tests?

Tags: automated-testing, java, cucumber, junit, mobile-automation

We are starting to automate web tests, but we don't know what is the best way to do, what is the best option to start and why?

And what is the best-easy to use for automate Mobile IOS and Android?

Comment: Hi. Please clarify your question with probably more details on the question caption.

Comment: hi @AlexeyR.
sorry, i write soo fast and didnt see haha i will improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Katalon is a software which can automate your test.
You have to create script (or use the macro builder) to execute your test

Cucumber is a software which use the gherkin language. It's not a tool which automate your test, it's a tool which help you to write your test in a behavior way.
You have to use another framework to execute your test.

Hope I help you :)

Comment: oh sorry, i use cucumber with java + junit and maven

Comment: Katalon Studio has added Cucumber support after version 5.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use Cucumber inside Katalon Studio. If you don't like its generated code you can write all the scripts yourself - Katalon doesn't prevent you from doing so. This tool will save you a lot of time setting up things for doing reporting, data driven testing, and API testing for your mobile app's backend which you would need someday.

Answer (score 1):

Testscripts generated or created with tools like Katalon, Visual Studio Test Professional or TestComplete are very hard to maintain. At first instance it looks easy to work with, but the use is very limited when compared to coding tests using for instance Protractor or Java in combination with Cucumber. Maintenance with GUI based (record and playback) test tools is very hard when applications tend to get grow. With coded tests you can use existing libraries and development environments and are not tied to the tool, you can do everything a developer can.

For testing Android or iOS apps I recommend Appium in combination with the language of your choice, like Java, C#, Python or Javascript.

Comment: As far as Katalon Studio is concerned: I agree that tests created using Web Recording / Spy option are hard to maintain, but Katalon also uses Groovy so you can easily write coded tests.

Answer (score 0):

Look today I work with the whole Microsoft platform and I see that using C # + selenium + Appium works perfectly for UI testing and mobile testing.

With this currently, the test power that would have on a single platform would indicate the visual studio, even for performance and load tests.

In addition to using code coverage, code analyst and code metrics.

Now free with the others informed, we have the python, java, and ruby.